# Reactjs Component called constructor when I use browser back Problem

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, next.js

My project on Next.js. I have a react component that returns a list of entities by filter. The filter is stored in state, entities are stored in redux. When I turn to another page and then I click the arrow back in the browser, the constructor is called and as a result the filter is cleaned, and the data in redux is filtered by the old filter that has disappeared. How do I solve this problem. I would not want to put the filter in the editor too and use it from there. Thanks!

Comment: It is not clear without some sample code. `popstate` event might help you https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/popstate

Comment: use getDerivedStateFromProps https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops

Comment: I brought out console.log. Yes, the filter value is shown there, but when going back and forth, it is reset.